# Select rows that have a unique value of one column for each unique value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input:

```
ITEM_NO | ORDER_NO | NAME
-------------------------
  123   |   100    | JOE
  123   |   101    | BOB
  123   |   101    | BOB
  124   |   101    | BOB
  456   |   102    | BOB
```

Desired Output:

```
ITEM_NO | ORDER_NO | NAME
-------------------------
  123   |   100    | JOE
  123   |   101    | BOB
  124   |   101    | BOB
  456   |   102    | BOB
```

Basically, I need to select all rows that have a unique ITEM_NO for each unique ORDER_NO.

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: If I knew how to use SELECT DISTINCT in such a way to accomplish what I need, I would not be here. :)

Comment: @cskowron try the given answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `DISTINCT` select

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO, ORDER_NO, NAME
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

OR

```
SELECT I.ITEM_NO, I.ORDER_NO, I.NAME 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO, ORDER_NO FROM <TABLE_NAME>) AS X
JOIN <TABLE_NAME> I ON I.ITEM_NO = X.ITEM_NO AND I.ORDER_NO = x.ORDER_NO
```